Programmatically spot blunders
I'm looking for a way to programmatically analyse a game (PGN) and produce an analysis of best moves.
I have a chess.com subscription but AFAIK they do not provide the analysis via API.
I'm open to suggestions, if this can be achieved with a lichess api or using stockfish on my local machine.
My programming language of choice would be python but that's not so relevant.
